# Receive touch event on any screen

Tags: android

I'm trying to make a custom navigation button and have disabled the default navigation buttons provided by android by rooting my device. I want my custom navigation buttons to disappear after some interval of time (say 5 seconds). I have managed to do so. I want to make something such that whenever I touch anywhere on the screen, I can detect the touch event and show my navigation bar. Whether I'm on homescreen or any application, I can receive touch event. Is there a way to do so or do I need to go android source code?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

OnCreate of your Service: used WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH flag.

```
@Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"onCreate", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        mView = new HUDView(this);
        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.TOP;
        params.setTitle("Load Average");
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        wm.addView(mView, params);
    }
```

Now, you will start getting each and every click event.

see this [Creating a system overlay window (always on top)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481226/creating-a-system-overlay-window-always-on-top)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I tried doing that but it didn't work. I can only receive events on the top most window. I searched a lot about it and I think that it no longer works for 4.X. If I'm wrong please let me know.